# Change gcc path for disutils

Tags: python, ubuntu, gcc, installation

in ubuntu 16, anaconda python 3.5,
when using setup.py and extension, disutils,
it uses /usr/bin/gcc

I would like to change to another path
(for example where conda gcc is installed).

but, don’t have sudo permission.

How to do it ?